# How to display popup model as per set time?

Tags: jquery, popup

I want to display popup model which time set by user. For example If user set 10:00 am. time for display popup then popup will display at 10.00 am.

How it is possible ?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this will execute every 5 minutes 
    // => Check the System time here
    // => show the Popup here
}, 300000);
```

Check the working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mm7b7t5t/)** for jquery popup.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can i set perfect time? Like I want to set 10.00 am. ... Current time is 9.00 pm.... can i set like this?

Comment: There's nothing that will give you the "current" interval, as there might be several distinct timers running. You might be better off constructing your own setInterval that stores the interval and that you can later query.